# Android NDK Callbacks to Java Activity

Tags: java, android, callback, android-ndk, native

I'm porting an application of mine so the majority of work is done within the native part of the application and the Java side is purely for my UI.

What I'm trying to implement at the moment is a ProgressBar that will show the status of a native thread's operation. The UI consists of different Activities and I'm intending to display the ProgressBars from those Activities.

The question is: How do I do it? I have some native code as follows:

```
jclass clazz = emv->FindClass( "com/example/myapp/MainActivity" );
```

That returns null for clazz. I realised that no MainActivity activity was actually being displayed at the time - it was an instance of my SettingsActivity, so I tried changing the above line accordingly but it still returned null.

Is it not possible to call FindClass() from native code to retrieve an Activity class?

Ultimately what I think I need to do is call a method such as below:

```
  public void ProgressUpdateFromNative( int i )
  {
    runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        DisplayProgressUpdate();
      }
    } );
  }
```

..and that is a method within one of my Activities.

```
jmethodID ProgressUpdateFromNative = env->GetMethodID( clazz, "ProgressUpdateFromNative", "(I)V");
env->CallObjectMethod( g_pObj, ProgressUpdateFromNative, 1 ) ;
```

I have retrieved the JavaVM pointer from my onLoad() JNI call and called JavaVM->AttachCurrentThread() to retrieve the env pointer used above.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing - ie -why I am getting null class returned from FindClass, or put me on a different track if what I am doing is completely wrong. I intended to read up on Handlers as well but I don't think I am that far through in my understanding just yet.

Note: I do realise I could poll some native variables from the Java UI but I would prefer a callback/event handling implementation rather than polling.

Comment: How is your native code where you do the `FindClass()` call invoked?

Comment: @Hans Kratz: I have a pthread running processing messages that are sent from the Java Activity to the native thread. The native thread runs continuously in a loop and processes any messages it gets from the Java UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is not invoked from a Java method it will use the system classloader in `FindClass()` which only knows about the Android system classes.

I suggest using getting a reference to the class in `JNI_OnLoad`, creating a global reference to that via `NewGlobalRef` and passing that to your threads or storing it in a global variable.

More info about this behavior: [http://markmail.org/message/25rrwp4va443rjuk#query:+page:1+mid:2u5wlkjyugwp75qa+state:results](http://markmail.org/message/25rrwp4va443rjuk#query%3a+page:1+mid:2u5wlkjyugwp75qa+state%3aresults)

Comment: I think you got the right answer. Just looking through my NDK Cookbook and I noticed that FindClass() is being called on a MainActivity within the OnLoad() function. I don't know what NewGlobalRef does but I'll do some reading and searching.

Comment: References to Java objects (such as a class) in JNI are usually only valid as long as the frame where they are obtained is life. In order to extend the lifetime you need to create a global reference to it. Beware that this will prevent the object that you created a global reference to from being garbage-collected. That is why it is important to delete the reference when you are done with it via `DeleteGlobalRef` for normal objects.

Comment: @Hand Kratz: Thanks for that. So if I was to obtain a global reference to an Activity, this would be a very bad thing wouldn't it? My MainActivity would always stay the same, but if the device was rotated then it would be recreated - so I would end up with 2 Activity objects persisting, correct? - Even though only one Activity would be valid and current. I was wondering earlier if it would have been possible to somehow 'register' an Activity with my native code whenever it is (re)created?

Comment: Sure you can call a native method via JNI in your activity's `onResume()` method to set the current activity. And in your native code you can delete the old global reference (if it is not null) and create a new global ref for the new activity. However: I suggest just calling back to a static method from your native code and doing all further processing in Java. This way you can avoid the NewGlobalRef/DeleteGlobalRef stuff except for the reference to your jclass.